# Examples of integrating moleculer-io with moleculer-web using moleculer-runner instead of ServiceBroker?

Tags: socket.io, moleculer

I am having fun with using moleculer-runner instead of creating a ServiceBroker instance in a moleculer-web project I am working on. The Runner simplifies setting up services for moleculer-web, and all the services - including the api.service.js file - look and behave the same, using a `module.exports = { blah }` format.

I can cleanly define the REST endpoints in the api.service.js file, and create the connected functions in the appropriate service files.  For example `aliases: { 'GET sensors': 'sensors.list' }`  points to the `list()` action/function in `sensors.service.js` .  It all works great using some dummy data in an array.

The next step is to get the service(s) to open up a socket and talk to a local program listening on an internal set address/port.  The idea is to accept a REST call from the web, talk to a local program over a socket to get some data, then format and return the data back via REST to the client.

**BUT** When I want to use sockets with moleculer, I'm having trouble finding useful info and examples on integrating moleculer-io with a *moleculer-runner-based* setup. All the examples I find use the ServiceBroker model. I thought my Google-Fu was pretty good, but I'm at a loss as to where to look to next.   Or, can i modify the ServiceBroker examples to work with moleculer-runner?  Any insight or input is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the following chain:
`localhost:3000/sensor/list -> sensor.list() -> send message to local program:8071 -> get response -> send response as return message to the REST caller.`

Then you need to add a socket io client to your `sensor` service (which has the `list()` action). Adding a client will allow it to communicate with "outside world" via sockets.

Check the image below. I think it has everything that you need.
As a skeleton I've used `moleculer-demo` project.

[image]

What I have:

- API service `api.service.js`. That handles the HTTP requests and passes them to the `sensor.service.js`
- The `sensor.service.js` will be responsible for communicating with remote socket.io server so it needs to have a socket.io client. Now, when the `sensor.service.js` service has `started()` I'm establishing a connection with a remote server located at port 8071. After this I can use this connection in my service actions to communicate with socket.io server. This is exactly what I'm doing in `sensor.list` action.
- I've also created `remote-server.service.js` to mock your `socket.io server`. Despite being a moleculer service, the `sensor.service.js` communicates with it via socket.io protocol.

Comment: Looks just about perfect.  Thanks for your input!  Awesome!  That is definitely more informative.

The only catch - and that is my mistake - is that the internal program is reachable not by http,  just a normal ip address and port ( ie: 192.1.68.1.121:8071 ) inside the local company network... it contains some  'business logic' that should not be exposed to the outside world.  But if i got it understood correctly, then I could just drop the http// in the ioClient in started() in the service?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It you want to skip the [protocol upgrade mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Protocol_upgrade_mechanism) then use directly `ws://my-ip:my-port` instead of ``http://my-ip:my-port``

Comment: We (the other developer on the project and I) just swapped out socket-io client package for the nodejs 'net' package - which we use in another project already for the same reason (talking to the internal net over sockets) - and that solved our later issue.  But thanks for reminder of the 'ws://' trick.. totally forgot about it.  Many thanks for the help!   Improved my understanding 3-fold.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter if your services use (or not) socket.io. All the services are declared in the same way, i.e., `module.exports = {}`

Below is a working example with socket.io.

```js
const { ServiceBroker } = require("moleculer");
const ApiGateway = require("moleculer-web");
const SocketIOService = require("moleculer-io");

const io = require("socket.io-client");

const IOService = {
  name: "api",
  // SocketIOService should be after moleculer-web
  // Load the HTTP API Gateway to be able to reach "greeter" action via:
  // http://localhost:3000/hello/greeter
  mixins: [ApiGateway, SocketIOService]
};

const HelloService = {
  name: "hello",

  actions: {
    greeter() {
      return "Hello Via Socket";
    }
  }
};

const broker = new ServiceBroker();

broker.createService(IOService);
broker.createService(HelloService);

broker.start().then(async () => {
  const socket = io("http://localhost:3000", {
    reconnectionDelay: 300,
    reconnectionDelayMax: 300
  });

  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("Connection with the Gateway established");
  });

  socket.emit("call", "hello.greeter", (error, res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
});
```

To make it work with `moleculer-runner` just copy the service declarations  into `my-service.service.js`. So for example, your `api.service.js` could look like:

```js
// api.service.js
module.exports = {
  name: "api",
  // SocketIOService should be after moleculer-web
  // Load the HTTP API Gateway to be able to reach "greeter" action via:
  // http://localhost:3000/hello/greeter
  mixins: [ApiGateway, SocketIOService]
}
```

and your `greeter` service:

```js
// greeter.service.js
module.exports = {
  name: "hello",

  actions: {
    greeter() {
      return "Hello Via Socket";
    }
  }
}
```

And run `npm run dev` or `moleculer-runner --repl --hot services`

Comment: I understood that, but as mentioned in my post I was looking for examples that *do not* require a ServiceBroker, since molecular-runner (according to the documentation) already does all the work the broker does.

Comment: I get what you need. This is why I've also added the "broker-free" example with the `api.service.js` and `greeter.service.js` files.
Anyway, use moleculer-cli to create a [moleculer demo project](https://moleculer.services/docs/0.13/usage.html#Create-a-Moleculer-project) and then copy the contents of `api.service.js`, as I've showed in my original post, into the API service that comes with the template.

Comment: Ok...I think I understand - probably just need more coffee.  The mixin part I got - already have that declared.  To be clear, when you say 'service declarations' are you including the content of `broker.start()`, and that it needs to be added to the api.service.js as...what?  A method? Or 'callBefore()'?   

And this still does not address receiving the REST call on one http port, then using a different socket to communicate with an internal program - although I think I can figure that out based on your example.

Much thanks for your input!  I'm *almost* there in my understanding.